# can we achieve 100 percent Abstaction using Dependency inversion principle?

Tags: java, android, solid-principles

In my daily programming i try my best to follow solid principle and other design pattern , but in some case it get hard ,specially using dependency inversion principle , for hierarchy classes it may be easy to create a factory class and store object there , also same as for singleton or builder , but problem occurs when you use single class object in method which is changing time to time and having no hierarchical relation likewise

//here in newTaskFor() Method the dip principle is getting violated
so how to tackle such problems on daily program or  its is ok to use new Keyword in container class

```
    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
     return new FutureTask<T>(callable);  //violating Dip principle
     }

/**
 * @throws RejectedExecutionException {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws NullPointerException       {@inheritDoc}
 */
public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<Void> ftask = newTaskFor(task, null);
    execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `or it is ok to use new Keyword in container class` ? First you mentioned `when you use single class object`. So, are there two classes in current example? Can you elaborate more on the example, please?

Comment: What does 100% abstraction mean? Is there a document stating this is a goal of the DIP?

Answer (score 0):

There's always concretions somewhere at some point. If you want to apply DIP for everything then almost all types will have to be hidden behind high-level specific interfaces over & over and it's just not pragmatic.

For instance, your high-level module that declares `newTaskFor` could very well craft it's own `Future` abstractions that wouldn't be directly coupled to the Java's native API, but that would probably be a lot of work for very little benefits?

A good example where I asked myself that question a lot is when I designed a simple web crawler library that had to manipulate HTML documents quite a lot. I had the choice between being coupled to a specific library like Jsoup or create my own abstractions to avoid tight coupling. Since I had to support complex document queries & manipulations at the end I found it very impractical to craft another abstraction layer on top of Jsoup where I'd have to redefine pretty much all node interfaces.

The key to abstracting effectively in those cases though is to only focus on the parts of the API your system really needs, leave the rest and make sure to express that abstraction in a domain-specific way. If you end up mimicing the whole API then your abstraction will most likely be highly influenced by the specific implementation anyway. **If you find that you need all the power of the underlying library then abstracting it away will probably be too costly.**

EDIT:

I just checked and it seems I lied in the third paragraph and I ended up crafting an API like the following (was years ago, it seems I went to only support the minimal use cases I had instead of a complex lib), but honeslty the `Scraper` would only support extremely basic extracting and the abstraction may have ended up doing more harm than good.

[image]